# Cannot post IEnumerable data in .NET Core Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, ienumerable

I have a C# .NET Core web application (*not* an MVC web app).  I’m trying to post data that is in an `IEnumerable` collection. For this post, I’ve simplified it:

In the CS file:

```
[BindProperty]
public IEnumerable<NpcpAllFields> NpcpAllFields { get; set; }
```

In the CSHTML file:

```
<form asp-page-handler="SaveData" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkBtn" formmethod="post">Submit</button><br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Sales Order Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Sales Order Line
            </th>
            <th>
                Is NPC
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var i in Model.NpcpAllFields)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" name="@i" asp-for="@i.SALES_ORD_NO"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" name="@i" asp-for="@i.SALES_ORD_LN_NO"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" name="@i" asp-for="@i.IS_A_NEW_PART"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</form>
```

The main code in question is the `foreach`:

```
@foreach (var i in Model.NpcpAllFields)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="@i" asp-for="@i.SALES_ORD_NO"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="@i" asp-for="@i.SALES_ORD_LN_NO"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="@i" asp-for="@i.IS_A_NEW_PART"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The above displays the data perfectly. But when I submit the data and check the `NpcpAllFields` collection in the debugger, it's empty.  The problem might be the value in the `name` field (I tried many different ways):

```
name="@i"
```

[image]

I was able to put the collection in a `for` loop (as opposed to a `foreach`) and it did populate the field in the debugger, but it does not display properly, it runs slow, and the data was incorrect.

I realize there are similar posts regarding this, but I could not find one that solved my issue.  Many posts/answers were for .NET Core *MVC* apps.

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing the incorrect value to the `name` attribute. Thus the `NpcpAllFields` are not bonded with value when submitting the form. Inspect the `<input>` elements in your `@foreach` statement and you will see the elements are rendered as:

```
<input class="form-control" name="<Namespace>.NpcpAllFields" />
```

Place the `@index` on the top of the page (After `@model`).

```
@{ int index = 0; }
```

Render the `name` attribute as below:

```
@foreach (var i in Model.NpcpAllFields)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="NpcpAllFields[@index].SALES_ORD_NO" asp-for="@i.SALES_ORD_NO"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="NpcpAllFields[@index].SALES_ORD_LN_NO" asp-for="@i.SALES_ORD_LN_NO"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" name="NpcpAllFields[@index].IS_A_NEW_PART" asp-for="@i.IS_A_NEW_PART"  />
        </td>
    </tr>

    index++;
}
```

Comment: To anyone that would happen upon this post, the above solution provided by Yong Shun WORKS perfectly.